# how to insert a shape with background color and outline in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In a user form I use a macro triggered by a button click that inserts a shape with text. That works fine but I have to make that shape background transparent with the outline red. The following code inserts a default shape that has a blue background without outline:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim shp As Shapes
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes
    With shp
        With .AddShape(msoShapeRectangularCallout, 50, 20, 50, 20).TextFrame
            .Characters.Text = TextBox1
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        End With
    End With
    Set shp = Nothing    
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you by chance try using the macro recorder? It should get you most if not all of the way there.

Comment: yes, i tried but that doesn't works, may be it's a diferent syntaxis

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the code you tried from the macro recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim shp As Shapes
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes
    With shp
        With .AddShape(msoShapeRectangularCallout, 50, 20, 50, 20)
            With .Line
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
            With .Fill
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0.65
            End With
            With .TextFrame
                .Characters.Text = TextBox1
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            End With
        End With
    End With
    Set shp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: oh thank you so much, that't exactly what i wanted to do :D

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I can offer some help. Please select the answer.